# additional blank module published in Artifactory through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to deploy a Gradle artifact using JFrog CLI command which works as expected. However, when running the build-collect-env command and publishing the build-info for it, it shows an additional blank module in the Jfrog build page which is not required. Below are the commands:

```
jfrog config add ******
jfrog rt gradle-config --server-id-deploy=*** --repo-deploy=***
jfrog rt gradle clean artifactoryPublish -b build.gradle --build-name=*** --build-number=***
jfrog rt build-collect-env <build-name> <build-num>
jfrog rt bp --build-url=*** <build-name> <build-num>
```

Note: This behavior is only when running inside a container through Jenkins pipeline whereas it works all fine if executed manually.

[image]

Comment: Can you please make sure that the build name and number are the same in "build-collect-env" and in the "jfrog rt gradle"? Also please make sure that the "build-collect-env" command runs in the same agent as the other command.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved in JFrog CLI version 2.12.0 as also described in this [Github issue](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/1349).